# Can an activity reference both Contact/Account and Incident

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom activity, and a customer want to have "RegardingObjectId" reference to a Account or Contact.
But also want a reference to a Incident.
Is this possible? And if so, what properies/methods are I looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can set activities in CRM regarding any entity that has been enabled for activities. Out of the box Account, Contact, and Case (the display name for Incident) are all among the activity enabled entities.

It does not matter that we are talking about a custom activity: Any activity can be set regarding any activity enabled entity.

You should thus already be able to set RegardingObjectId to either Account, Contact, or Case (though only one at a time).

As I understand it, you want to have a lookup to either Account or Contact while on the same CustomActivity also having a reference to a Case. It is not possible to have multiple regarding-style fields. Instead, you can add a normal 1:N-relationship from Case to your CustomActivity and add that as a lookup field on your CustomActivity form. In that way the regarding-field would be used for Account/Contact, while the lookup would be used for Case.

Comment: But our customer want regarding set to both a Contact and a Case at the same time

Comment: OK, I expanded on the answer suggesting you use a normal 1:N-relationship from Case to your CustomActivity.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've approached this is that the Regarding object is the *primary reference*. I then set up auxiliary lookups for the additional relationships.  So for example:

- Custom activity is in regards to this contact
- It is also related to a custom entity, so a lookup is there and set for the custom entity.
- It is also related to a case, so a separate 1:N relationship to Case is established with a lookup that is set to that Case.

The added benefit here is that the user gets to decide what the additional relationships are.  Then when you set up the grids on the custom entity and case (for my example) you set the relationship to the additional lookups and not the regarding.